# LaTeX and accessibility

Tags: acrobat, accessibility, mathml, ocr

I work as a manuscript editor with only so much LaTeX knowledge (though I am in the process of learning so I can better assist students). At my University, we've begun requiring accessible documents from students. For that, we mean that all PDFs must pass Acrobat's Accessibility Checker without error. This, of course, is a problem for LaTeX users. I came across a past question here that walked through using the Action Wizard option in Acrobat Pro to make the document accessible. This is great, so long as the manuscript only uses characters that are recognizable by Acrobat. The problem comes when special characters are used, usually ones that go across multiple lines of text, such as integrals, large parentheses, brackets around matrices, large square roots, etc. When Acrobat runs these through the OCR, large parentheses can show up all throughout the document (even on pages without any offending characters). Here is an example:
[image: Random parenthesis]

I can usually delete them, but this doesn't solve everything. The real problem is that these symbols are not *really* being OCRed properly, so the document isn't *really* accessible. Those characters cannot be read, because Acrobat does not have a font for them.

We've decided, then, that the best possible solution is likely to have students take a screenshot of any offending equations and replace the equation in the document with an image. Then, they would need to add alternate text to explain the equation to readers with low/no vision. So, I've been trying to find a way to convert LaTeX to something like Nemeth Mathspeak so that students can input their equation from LaTeX and get back appropriate alternate text. Any advice on making LaTeX code into something screen-reader friendly?

I saw another University suggest to their students the use of MathMagic or MathType. MathMagic's files are not compatible with my Mac and MathType costs money--money I certainly don't want to spend if I don't know if it will do what I'm hoping it will do. The claim is that these programs can turn an LaTeX code into an image or MathML which *can* be read by a screen-reader. Could MathType make an image that can be inserted into the document to replace the LaTeX equations that could then be OCRed properly?

Is there something I'm not thinking of that could help solve this issue?

Comment: To me, a GFOM, this seems to be a problem with Acrobats Accessibilty Checker. I have never had a problem printing a PDF file generated from LaTeX, so why should the Accessibilty Checker barf?

Comment: Which engine do your students use? Is switching to lualatex possible?

Comment: @PeterWilson I agree that this is largely a problem with LaTeX and Acrobat not working together properly. I'm sure if Acrobat weren't so...conservative with their font options, this wouldn't even be an issue. The only other thing I can think of is to let the manuscripts go without going through all of the steps in the Action Wizard, but that leaves Acrobat flagging the document as being entirely comprised of unrecognized characters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Most of them use Overleaf, so I think they probably default to pdfLaTeX. Would using lualatex or xelatex make a significant difference?

Comment: do you have to use pdf, currently  if you convert the latex source to html+mathml you will find it easier to generate accessible documents (latexml and tex4ht can both usually both usually be used)

Comment: well with lualatex or xelatex they could use unicode-math and this could improve the automatic detection of math.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately, PDF is the only option. They are not only filed in our electronic repository, but they are uploaded to ProQuest/UMI which requires a PDF as a primary document. It might not be a bad idea to ask LaTeX students to upload a supplemental non-PDF file that is accessible for those that rely on screen-readers, though.

Comment: I should certainly try using lualatex and the unicode-math package in that case, then all (almost all) math symbols will be encoded using standard unicode positions rather than legacy 8-bit tex-spoecific math font encodings. so acrobat will at least have a chance to recognise the characters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That might actually solve a lot of these issues. Since unicode is universal, any characters should be readable by Acrobat (theoretically). Since my LaTeX knowledge is limited, then, I should ask my LaTeX students to use either lualatex or xelatex and install the unicode-math package to go with this? Since we use a template, is it possible for me to add unicode-math to our template package? From there, I would need to add 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf} to the code?

Comment: unicode-math doesn't need to be installed. It is in all the standard distributions and available on overleaf  see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles%2FOpenType-based_math_typesetting:_An_introduction_to_the_STIX2_OpenType_fonts (that;s using stix, but pagella math would be just the same)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sweet! So then, adding the \usepackage command to our template should help to fix this?

Comment: well you should test a bit. Perhaps you will need have to adapt the text fonts too. Also only because  every math symbol has an unicode mapping doesn't mean that the math structure can be deduced.  You should perhaps also use tex4ht to get a mathml representation which you can use as additional alternate text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Absolutely. I'm very excited to start trying to figure this out. I've spent months working on this independently and it has been so frustrating. I'm happy just to have a new direction to try.

Comment: we are working on getting accessible pdf out of latex "out of the box" see https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2020-tagged-pdf-feasibility.pdf  but note the timelines on that project, that will come but not for your current set of students, sorry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've stumbled across that before! That is great news, considering the current state of education and how many students we're finding are using screen-readers. I'll continue trying to do my best to figure out solutions for the current grad students in the meantime. Thanks for all you do!